# JSF - selectManyListbox comes with items already selected

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a simple problem and I hope that the solution is also so simple...

The items in my selectManyListbox all comes already selected per default and I don't want this.

I searched everywhere for possible options but I found nothing.

Can someone help me, please?

```
<h:selectManyListbox 
     value="#{detailModel.afterObject.businessObjectAttributeSpecifications}" 
     size="10"> 
    <f:selectItems 
       value="#{detailModel.getSetAsList(detailModel.afterObject.businessObjectAttribut‌​eSpecifications)}"/> 
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

Thank you in advance
Francesco

Comment: Please post the listbox's source code. Maybe there is a problem with with the value attribute and the selectItems.

Comment: Here is the code regarding the listbox:`code` <h:selectManyListbox value="#{detailModel.afterObject.businessObjectAttributeSpecifications}" size="10">
 <f:selectItems value="#{detailModel.getSetAsList(detailModel.afterObject.businessObjectAttributeSpecifications)}"/>
</h:selectManyListbox>`code`

Comment: Copied the code into your question and added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same list for the `selectItems` and the `value` attribute. Use a different list ( such as `selectedObjects`) in the `value` attribute to hold the selection, eg:

```
<h:selectManyListbox 
     value="#{detailModel.afterObject.selectedBusinessObjectAttributeSpecifications}" 
     size="10"> 
    <f:selectItems 
       value="#{detailModel.getSetAsList(detailModel.afterObject.businessObjectAttribut‌​eSpecifications)}"/> 
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a default item with text `Please Select` and treat it programatically